# No tests found with test runner JUnit5

Tags: spring, maven, junit, pom.xml

I have just started learning Junit and created a very trivial test class but I get two problems
i) Cant run as JUnit test directly.(i have to run configurations for every java file i try to run in eclipse idk why is that)
ii) I followed several answers for the same problem but no help--no tests found with test runner JUnit 5

I have tried solutions of
adding dependencies,
restarting,
other solutions provided in similar posts

```
package io.javatest;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class MathUtilsTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
        System.out.println("This test ran");
    }

}

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.javatest</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-5-basics</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>junit-5</name>

  <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.4.0</junit.jupiter.version>
        <junit-platform.version>1.2.0</junit-platform.version>
  </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.0</version> 
         <scope>test</scope> 
        </dependency>`enter code here`
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example junit 5 project using maven with an example test.  The test runs using "mvn test" at the command line.

https://github.com/cameronhurd/junit5-example

Answer (score 0):

In your IDE, right click on the junit test case and select "Run as" and click on "Run configurations", select the configuration and scroll down and change "Test Runner" to junit 4. Now apply and close and Run. This solved issue for me. But would like to know the root cause.